# How can I pass a detail object to custom authorization in tastypie?

Tags: django, tastypie

How can I access the detail endpoint object being accessed in the request during a tastypie authorization?

I noticed that one of the overridden methods in the [docs](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/v0.9.11/authentication_authorization.html#implementing-your-own-authentication-authorization) has an object parameter -- how can I set this?

Comment: So far, my best solution is to use the path attribute of the request object.  This seems hackish...

Answer (score 3):

In branch perms,

https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/perms/tastypie/authorization.py

Class Authorization has a set of methods for example:

```
def read_detail(self, object_list, bundle):
    """
    Returns either ``True`` if the user is allowed to read the object in
    question or throw ``Unauthorized`` if they are not.
    Returns ``True`` by default.
    """
    return True
```

Here You can try to access *the obj* through **bundle.obj**

If You can't use the perms branch, I suggest you this way:

```
class MyBaseAuth(Authorization):
    def get_object(self, request):
        try:
            pk = resolve(request.path)[2]['pk']
        except IndexError, KeyError:
            object = None # or raise Exception('Wrong URI')
        else:
            try:
                object = self.resource_meta.object_class.objects.get(pk=pk)
            except self.resource_meta.DoesNotExist:
                object = None
        return object


class FooResourceAuthorization(MyBaseAuth):
    def is_authorized(self, request, object=None):
        if request.method in ('GET', 'POST'):
            return True
        elif request.method == 'DELETE':
            object = self.get_object(request)
            if object.profile = request.user.profile:
                return True
        return False
```

Comment: I'm not sure I can move to that branch -- there are lots of other changes I would have to review.

Answer (score 0):

Hackish, but with a simple way of getting to the object from the request URL (inspired by the code inside DjangoAuthorization).

```
def is_authorized(self, request, object=None):

    meta = self.resource_meta
    re_id = re.compile(meta.api_name + "/" + meta.resource_name + "/(\d+)/")
    id = re_id.findall(request.path)

    if id:
        object = meta.object_class.objects.get(id=id[0])

        # do whatever you want with the object
    else:
        # It's not an "object call"
```