# Tastypie - Get list of objects being editted (PUT/PATCH)

Tags: django, api, rest, tastypie

I am trying to do authorization in away that only owners of the objects can edit them.

How can i get the ids of the objects being edited in the post call in my authorization method?

Eg: If someone PUTs to the url `/api/v1/resource_name/1`, I want to get '**1**'

Also, tastypie allows a collection of objects to be edited at one go. (http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/interacting.html#updating-a-whole-collection-of-resources-put) 
Is there a way for me to get a list of the objects being edited in any call?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with this as well.  Right now, I determine the object by parsing request.path.  I believe a more direct method (via the object parameter in Authorization() for example) will become available in 0.9.12 and beyond.

You might watch this question as well: [How can I pass a detail object to custom authorization in tastypie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423030/how-can-i-pass-a-detail-object-to-custom-authorization-in-tastypie).

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Erik. Have you thought about overriding obj_update to do this somehow? I got the clue from here : http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#creating-per-user-resources You can access bundle in this method and check the id. If things dont look right you could create a BadRequest. Ill try it out and keep you updated

Comment: Seems possible -- will try that approach as well.

Comment: Seems path/URI parsing is the only solution right now.  Not a bad one, since URIs are a common way of addressing resources anyway.